# OS Web GIS for a travel blog

Tags: open-source-gis, web-gis

I have had this idea for years now and would finally like to fulfil it! I was always bothered by text-heavy travel blogs. Therefore, I aim to have a Web-GIS based travel blog in two years time. The idea is to start the homepage with a user-friendly map showing my travel routes worldwide linking it to photo albums and text. The map itself would show major information like the actual travel route and highlight places with recommendations linked to further texts.

Unfortunately I have no idea about how such a process could possibly start. I know I need way more info on how to create a homepage. So far I'm only experienced in desktop GIS versions. I hope you can give me some first hints and links. Things I haven’t thought about to start the project.

Comment: How much programming are you able to do? Not that it would require TOO much, but you'll have to do some... there are several options I think would fit your project nicely...

Comment: Like which? My programming skills equal zero.

Comment: What about GIS skills? Do you know QGIS or CartoDB?

Comment: Yes, quite good skills with QGIS Desktop.

Comment: since someone closed this question (!?!) I can only comment that you should create your route in QGIS, upload it to CartoDB, and put your photos in a Picasa Web Album and geotag them. CartoDB has a paid feature called 'sync', so you can sync your Picasa KML feed (geotagged photos) to your CartoDB map... get in touch if you want to know more...

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out the work of Bjørn Sandvik at the [Thematic Mapping](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/) blog. Very inspirational stuff with lots of technical walk-throughs, and a good mix of desktop GIS and programming.

A recent example looks at mapping out a cross country ski trip:  http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2015/03/nordryggen-on-skis-for-25-days-creating_20.html

Comment: I think this is pretty close to what OP has in mind. From the same author there is Leaflet Photo: http://blog.mastermaps.com/2014/08/showing-geotagged-photos-on-leaflet-map.html And if self-hosting the images: http://gisforthought.com/self-hosted-leaflet-photo/